# Executing AJAX scripts within an AJAX response

Tags: ajax

I'm having trouble using AJAX page updates along with other AJAX scripts.
During a normal page load, the AJAX scripts (picture scrolling and picture thumbnails) work fine.  But when I update a page with AJAX, these scripts (usually loaded in the header of the initial page load) stop working.

I am wondering if this is specific to these scripts and I need to look into them deeper to resolve/re-write or if I am missing something more generic in combining AJAX page updates with AJAX scripts the returned code relies on.

Embedded javascript runs fine.

Thanks for your ideas!

PS: The scripts I am using are from www.dynamicdrive.com are:
1)  stepcarousel (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm) and 
23) thumbnailviewer (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail.htm)  from the

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this on Firefox, using the Firebug debugger, so you can single-step through and determine what is going on with the javascript.  If you are using IE8 then you can hit F12 and bring up the debugger for that environment also.

Once you have some idea what is going on then you can explain what you are seeing, what browsers you have tried and you will get more help.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I do use FireBug, but not not all of the features.  I will investigate further before posting another question about it.